# Validation of form input fields in React

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, reactjs

```
<div className="form-group">
  <label className="col-sm-0 control-label"> Name : &nbsp; </label>
  <input
    type="text"
    value={this.state.UserName}
    onChange={this.handleChangeUserName}
    placeholder="Name"
    pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}"
    className="form-control"
  />
</div>
```

Hi, I am trying to validate a form input field in React using pattern validation. But it's not working. I am using validation as simple as `pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}"`.

Kindly let me know how to work this out. Putting validation in React Bootstrap component.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the value property (means controlled component) of `input` element and updating the state in `onChange` method, So you can easily test this regex in `onChange` and update the state only when the input will be valid.

Like this:

```
handleChangeUserName(e){
   if(e.target.value.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$") != null){
       this.setState({UserName: e.target.value});
   }
}
```

Check the working code:

```js
class HelloWidget extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={UserName:''}
    this.handleChangeUserName = this.handleChangeUserName.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChangeUserName(e){
    if(e.target.value.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$")!=null) {
      this.setState({UserName: e.target.value});
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="form-group">
        <label className="col-sm-0 control-label" htmlFor="textinput"> Name : &nbsp; </label>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.UserName} onChange={this.handleChangeUserName}  placeholder="Name" className="form-control"></input>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
  
ReactDOM.render(<HelloWidget/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container' />
```

Check the `jsfiddle` for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/uL4fj4qL/11/

Check this `jsfiddle`, `Material-Ui snackbar` added to show the error, if user tries to enter the wrong value: https://jsfiddle.net/4zqwq1fj/

Comment: No it's not validating for text which I input

Comment: what validation do u want? the regex i used validate whether its a character or not, it will not allow user to write any num. did u check the `jsfiddle` what is the issue in that?

Comment: hi its working for me now, i had done some mistake regarding variable.

Comment: Can u pls tell me how do I add popup or a comment if user tries to enter anything other than alphabets ?

Comment: since you are using reactjs, u can use the awesome Material-Ui components, check the snackbar, use it for showing the error: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/snackbar

Comment: check the updated answer, i added a `jsfiddle` link, basic snackbar example to show the error. Let me know if u need any help in this. i think now it solved ur problem, mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 9):

`pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}"` is a feature from [HTML5](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/).

Complete solution here: https://codepen.io/tkrotoff/pen/qypXWZ?editors=0010

### If you only want to use default HTML5 validation:

```
class FormValidate extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: ''
  };

  handleUsernameChange = e => {
    console.log('handleUsernameChange()');
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    console.log('handleSubmit() Submit form with state:', this.state);
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="username">Name</label>
          <input
            id="username"
            name="username"
            value={this.state.username}
            onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}
            placeholder="Name"
            pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}"
            className="form-control" />
        </div>

        <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Invalid input FormValidate]

### If you want to better integrate with [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#validation):

```
class FormNoValidate extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: '',
    error: ''
  };

  handleUsernameChange = e => {
    console.log('handleUsernameChange()');
    const target = e.target;
    this.setState({
      username: target.value,
      error: target.validationMessage
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    console.log('handleSubmit() Submit form with state:', this.state);
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="username">Name</label>
          <input
            id="username"
            name="username"
            value={this.state.username}
            onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}
            placeholder="Name"
            pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}"
            className="form-control" />
          <div className="invalid-feedback d-block">
            {this.state.error}
          </div>
        </div>

        <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Invalid input FormNoValidate]

### If you want to go further (more features, more control, better integration):

I've written a very simple React library to deal with form validation and that supports HTML5 attributes: https://github.com/tkrotoff/react-form-with-constraints

Examples here: https://github.com/tkrotoff/react-form-with-constraints/blob/master/README.md#examples

Answer (score 3):

with React hook, we can build custom hook to make validation much easier. with your example blow. you can easily by adding `register` method from react hook form: https://github.com/bluebill1049/react-hook-form

```
import React from 'react';
import useForm from 'react-hook-form';

function Test() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  return {
    <form className="form-group" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label className="col-sm-0 control-label"> Name : &nbsp; </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={register}
          placeholder="Name"
          pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}"
          className="form-control"
        /> 
     </div>
  }
}
```