# Form validation using Spy by Sinon gets wrong

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, sinon, spy

I'm unable to verify if a form is rightfully filled using the `Spy()` function of Sinon.
My goal is to pass this unit test:

```
  it('check entire form validation when the form is valid', () => {
     let formSpy = spy();
     const form = mount(<Form isFormValid={formSpy} />);
     form.find('.name').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'sasrank' } });
     form.find('.email').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'aasdbc@xyz.com' } });
     form.find('.phone').simulate('change', { target: { value: '9856756756' } });
     form.find('.url').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'http://google.com' } });
     form.find('.button').simulate('click');
     expect(formSpy.calledWith(true)).toEqual(true);
  });
```

This form uses some basic HTML5 validations

`Form.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {PropTypes} from 'prop-types';

class Form extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isEmailValid: false,
        isNameValid: false,
        isPhoneValid: false,
        isUrlValid: false,
    };

}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="row">
        <h1 className="text-center">Form Validation</h1>
        <form>
            <h3>Name:
            </h3>
            <input type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,30}" className="name"></input>
            <h3>Email:
            </h3>
            <input type="email" required className="email"></input>
            <h3>Phone:
            </h3>
            <input type="number" required className="phone"></input>
            <h3>Blog URL:
            </h3>
            <input type="url" required className="url"></input>
            <div className="small-6 small-centered text-center columns">
                <button href="#" className="button success expand round text-center">Verify</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>);
  }
 }

export default Form;
```

What can I modify in order to get this test be passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `isFormValid` anywhere in `Form`. React doesn't know magically what to do with `isFormValid` passed to `React.Component` constructor (unless you're using some magical library you didn't mentioned.

It's not "sinon", it's lack of proper implementation that calls `isFormValid`

At minimum, you should install `onClick` callback on your button and call this validate with some values, like this:

```
<button onClick={this.handleSubmit} ...>Verify</button>
```

And `onSubmit` method that looks more or less like this:

```
onSubmit = (event) => {
    const valuues = collectValues();
    if (this.props.isFormValid(values)) {
        // ... handle submit
    }
}
```

There are lot of places where form validation is used, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51598466/269448) that also uses form [HTML5 validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_forms_using_JavaScript) (not sure if enzyme supports it though)